# How to parse data from json in android?

Tags: android, json

I have called `webservice` from android and got a response as below.....

Result from WebService =

```
11-30 13:21:16.304: DEBUG/Inside SOAP(512): JSON output {
11-30 13:21:16.304: DEBUG/Inside SOAP(512):   "_str": "anyType{string\u003dImplements and Equipments; string\u003dInsurance; string\u003dIrrigation and Water; }"
11-30 13:21:16.304: DEBUG/Inside SOAP(512): }
```

Now I want to parse these results and store in my `SQLite` database. How it can be done? I need your help please...

Comment: your service return invalid json String

Comment: See my answer [here][2]


And a Question [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381896/handle-server-response-in-android
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033305/json-file-not-getting-downloaded-function-returns-null/8033471#8033471

It will help you..

Comment: I am getting this result from webservice....                anyType{string=Implements and Equipments; string=Insurance; string=Irrigation and Water; }                                            How to parse this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get every string that follows an "=" and precedes a ";"

Here's a simple example:

```
// This is the string you want to parse
String searchableString = "string=first; string=second; string=third";

int indexOfEqualsSign = searchableString.indexOf("=");
int indexOfSemicolon = searchableString.indexOf(";");

while (indexOfEqualsSign >= 0) {
    String result = searchableString.substring(indexOfEqualsSign + 1, indexOfSemicolon);
    System.out.print(result);
    indexOfEqualsSign = searchableString.indexOf("=", indexOfSemicolon);
}
```

The output of the example looks like this:

```
first
second
third
```

Comment: @Imran khan sorry but i got the result is in the form as Result from WebService = FillAutoCompleteBudgetMasterItemsByMasterIdResponse{FillAutoCompleteBudgetMasterItemsByMasterIdResult=anyType{string=Implements and Equipments; string=Insurance; string=Irrigation and Water; }; }
Now plz tell me how can I parse it using JSON