# Can't extrack information from JSON File

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

[Android] I have a JSON File that it is composed in this way:

```
 "5":{
        "15":{
            ...
        },
        "18":{
           ..
        },
        "7":{
            ...
        },
        "9":{
            ..
        }
    }
}
```

How I can extract the infomation at 15,18,7,9? this number 15, 18 ,7, 9 change from run to another..
My Code is:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(file);
            JSONArray uno = obj.getJSONArray("5");
```

and I obtain JSONException!! Anyone can help me?

Comment: asked bazillion times ... "Alex", "Kodie","Lache" are keys (in json terminology)... now, get back to googling

Comment: of course you do. look at the structure of your json file. now look at the method you call. now look at the doc for the method you call if that's not clear enought already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse data from json in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620414/how-to-parse-data-from-json-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

5 is not a JSONarray, it is a key.  Try obj["5"] from the above documentation, then calling keys to get the keys to access the internal attributes.

Comment: that is the second problem ... in fact seems like OP knows nothing about JSON ...

Comment: Yes and after how can extract the other information the JSON object?

Comment: @Gozilla,  Read the linked documentation for "keys".  It returns an iterator over all the string keys inside of "5".